# How to add a custom layer in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, layer

I want to add a layer, all the element of previous layer `<0.5` is `0` and all the element of previous layer `>=0.5` is `1`.
Do you know how to do that?

Comment: do you mean **activation from previous layer** by `all the element of previous layer`  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Modified ReLU activation with some division operation. The following solution is little modified because, it outputs 0 for x == 0.5.

The output O(x) can be rewritten as

[image: equ1]

Now the custom layer would be

```py
class CustomReLU(Layer):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomReLU, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):

        super(CustomReLU, self).build(input_shape)  

    def call(self, x):
        relu = ReLU()
        output = relu(x-0.5)/(x-0.5)
        return output

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape
```

### Edit:

For x=0.5 the above equation and code can easily be modified to the following.
[image: equ1],
where `(x==0.5)` is evaluated to 1 if x is equal to 0.5 and 0 eitherwise.

```py
import keras.backend as K

class CustomReLU(Layer):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustomReLU, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):

        super(CustomReLU, self).build(input_shape)  

    def call(self, x):
        relu = ReLU()
        output = relu(x-0.5)/(x-0.5) + K.cast(K.equal(x, 0.5), K.floatx())
        return output

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape
```